# Convert string with date of a week

Tags: java, datetime

I've got an error when I try to convert this string to date:

```
String s = "Mon, 11-12-2021 - 12:00";
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(s, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, MM-dd-yyyy - HH:mm"));
```

I got this:

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Mon, 11-12-2021 - 12:00' could not be parsed at index 0

    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
    at Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

Is it possible in Java to convert this string or it should be changed in some way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps your locale is not English. Then you would need to pass `Locale.ENGLISH` to your DateTimeFormatter.

This worked for me, together with @Narcis Postolache's date change to `Fri`.

```java
String s = "Fri, 11-12-2021 - 12:00";
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(s, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, MM-dd-yyyy - HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH));
```

localDateTime object: 2021-11-12T12:00

Answer (score 0):

Try
String s = "Fri, 11-12-2021 - 12:00";

Comment: thanks for an answer, but it gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

Your defaul locale is not US and 11-12-2021 is not Monday it's Friday:

```
String s = "Fri, 11-15-2021 - 12:00";
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(s, 
          DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, MM-dd-yyyy - HH:mm", Locale.US));
```

Answer (score 0):

For the pattern you are requesting it might be a good idea to specify a different *predefined formatter* according to the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) (have a look to see the different options)

```
String pattern = "Mon, 11 Dec 2021 12:00:00 GMT";
LocalDate formatter = LocalDate.parse(pattern, DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME);
```

Additionally, if you don't want to convert the month you can do:

```
LocalDateTime local = LocalDateTime.parse("2021-12-11T12:00:00");
```

and then get the day of the week with:

```
System.out.println(local.getDayOfWeek());
```